# missing value replaced with the next available one keeping the column header

Tags: excel

I have a csv with the column of Product1, Product2, Product3.....Product12.

Some of the product value is missing and I would like if the product value is missing for one product to get the value for the next product that has a value available

i.e. if product1 product3 and product5 are empty to show the first 12 products with the value inherited from the next product and last 3 products to be empty in this case because there is 3 empty products.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHDRu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the following steps:

To delete blank cells and move left, you just need to select all blank cells and delete them then shift right.

1. Select the data range, **press Ctrl + G** to enable Go To dialog, and click Special.
2. In the Go To Special dialog, check **Blanks option**, and click OK
3. All the empty cells have been selected in the range, right click at one of these blanks, and select **Delete** from the context menu.
4. In the Delete dialog, check **Shift cells left** option, and click OK.
5. Then the blank cells have been deleted and the data have been moved left

Comment: if the solution works, please feel free to accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers